# Trying to use .live with .toggle

Tags: jquery

I have tables that let you toggle between editable forms and the values. I also have a function that lets me dynamically add table clones. I need to be able to use the same toggle functionality on the newly created tables.

I tried using the .live function for the toggle but this causes me to have to make an extra click before the editable forms appear. How can I resolve this issue so I only need to click once?

```
$('.block a.submit').live('click', function(){
    $('.block a.submit').toggle(
        function(){
            $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
                $(".value", this).hide();
                $(".edit", this).show();
                $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
                $('thead').show();
            });
        },
        function(){
            $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
                $(".edit", this).hide();
                $(".value", this).show();
                $('thead').hide();
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Here is a rough mock up of what I am trying to accomplish. The only main difference is the forms are initially hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/z5C2F/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.block a.submit').live('click', function(){
    $(this).toggle(//you need to use this
        function(){
            $(this).text('Save').parent().each(function(){
                $(".value", this).hide();
                $(".edit", this).show();
                $(this).find('.edit :first').focus(); //focuses on first form element - less clicks
                $('thead').show();
            });
        },
        function(){
            $(this).text('Edit').parent().each(function(){
                $(".edit", this).hide();
                $(".value", this).show();
                $('thead').hide();
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: still requires that extra click

Comment: can you post some of ur code on jsfiddle, this is hard to do without any markup

Comment: Is this a good example. The main difference is the form is initially hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/z5C2F/

Comment: @Neal just trying to alert you.

Comment: im really not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have a div.edit which has forms to fill and a div.value which display the values of those forms both nested in a div.block. When you hit the edit button or double click the div.block it toggles between the div.edit and div.value. Right now it takes an extra click to toggle the div.edit and div.value. So if I were to initiate the toggle by double clicking it takes 3 clicks and to toggle by just clicking the edit button it takes 2 clicks. I need to get rid of that extra click.

Comment: ahhh can u write that with better formatting as an update to ur question? (along with the fiddle link)

Comment: @Justin, better formatting means that it is readable. one jumble of a paragraph is **NOT** readable. and updates usually go at the end of ur orig question

Comment: @Justin not sure if if matters to you. Adding .trigger('click') to the toggle make this script perfect. Ie., $(this).toggle(function(),function()).trigger('click'). Hit me up if you need a fiddle.